# Returning rows with certain column values in python

Tags: python

I am reading a text file titled "sample.txt" with 2 columns of data as follows.

ID      Type

1       A

2       B

3       A

4       C

5       A

Now,

1) I want to only return rows whose 'Type' column value is 'A' and

2) I want to only return rows whose 'Type' column value is not 'A'.

Can anyone help me understand how this can be done in python? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/2901002).

Comment: thanks @jezrael for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't try very hard or at least didn't provide your attempts at cracking this.

```
def filterFileLines(filterFunction):
    with open("sample.txt") as file:
        # discard_first_line
        file.readline()

        for line in file:
            id, type = line.strip().split(' ')
            if filterFunction(id, type):
                print (line, end='')
        print('')

def isTypeA(a, b):
    return b == 'A'

def isNotTypeA(a, b):
    return not isTypeA(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Lines with type == "A"')
    filterFileLines(isTypeA)

    print('lines with type not "A"')
    filterFileLines(isNotTypeA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was able to figure it out from another post suggested by @jezrael.